# Lunar Seas and Sun Hills at a sports park?

Tags: meaning

I was reading the introduction page for [Kirara Memorial Park](http://www.kirara-memorial-park.jp/introduce.html) (a public sports park) in Japan, and one of the features they listed was a `「月{つき}の海{うみ}」`. As far as I can tell, in both [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_mare) and [Japanese](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AE%E6%B5%B7) this phrase only really has the meaning of "Lunar mare" or "Lunar seas" (the dark sections we can see on the moon). However, clearly this park's `月の海` is just a nice relaxing beach: [see here](http://www.kirara-memorial-park.jp/introduce/moon_sun.html#moon).

Next to their `月の海`, there is a `「太陽の丘」`. If I had seen this by itself I would have just assumed it was the name of their hill...Google seems to confirm that it's just a cool name to give a hill. This makes me think they're going with a sun/moon naming theme, but I can't say that with authority.

What my question is, is there an apparent reason why they're calling their beach `月の海`? By that I mean is there something I'm missing (a play on words or whatnot) that a Japanese person would catch and understand? Or is it just (as far as anyone can tell) a name they gave their beach (which, by the way, I think is an awesome name!).

Comment: I can't say for sure if it's related to this, but there is a famous song called 月の砂漠, inspired by a beach in Chiba Prefecture.

Comment: Not quite sure, but it seems to me very akin to naming the two places "Moon Beach" and "Sun Hill." I don't think there's any particular logic to it, but I'll add this as a comment since I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason in particular. Things get named like that, even/especially obscenely mundane things, to market them and make them seem special. You will see a lot of noncontroversial (often borderline propagandistic-sounding) "good things" in names like these. i.e. "Happiness," "Lovely," "Bright," and things that children like, like stars, the moon and the sun. There is no underlying meaning.